# Redirect a php page to multiple random links in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a redirect system on my site that will redirect a user from one php page to another random pages.

```
$rand_link=rand(20,60);
if($rand_link > 20)
{$link="/page2.php";}
if($rand_link > 30)
{$link="/page3.php";}
else
{$link="/default.php";}
header('Location: $link');
```

Is not working, this code is on my "main.php" file, when I enter "/main.php" I am getting redirected to 404 page of my hosting service.

Is there something wrong with my code?

How can I minimise this code? I have more then 15 links to redirect randomly?

Any help would be greatly appriciated?

Comment: The duplicate exactly shows you the difference between single and double quotes and that variables aren't parsed in single quotes. <- And that is exactly the problem in your code + the solution to use double quotes

Comment: good this post also solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between single quotes (`'`), variables are not interpreted.

Use double quotes:

```
header("Location: $link");
```

or, use string concatenation:

```
header('Location:'.$link);
```

To randomize:

```
$rand=rand(1,15);
header('Location:/page'.$rand.'.php');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used double quotes inside the header function and it solved the problem,